# Java How to get the sum up all the of the values of each enum

Tags: java, enums, sum

I am trying to understand how I could get all of the values for each enum, and add all of it together in one variable. my code.

```
enum Junk {

Wrapper(0),
SilverCoins(150), 
Dresser(250),
Sofa(250),
ChippedBat(0),
BrokenMicrowave(0),
SilverWare(35),
Newspapers(0),
Book(20),
Clothes(60),
Plates(40),
Cups(25),
DiningTable(200),
Chair(30),
BoxOfPaper(10),
BucketofPaint(10),
Watch(30);

}
```

I would like to know how I could add all of the values of each enum and adding it together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is your complete code that you may expect.

```
package enumtest;

enum Junk
{
    Wrapper(0),
    SilverCoins(150),
    Dresser(250),
    Sofa(250),
    ChippedBat(0),
    BrokenMicrowave(0),
    SilverWare(35),
    Newspapers(0),
    Book(20),
    Clothes(60),
    Plates(40),
    Cups(25),
    DiningTable(200),
    Chair(30),
    BoxOfPaper(10),
    BucketofPaint(10),
    Watch(30);

    private int value;

    private Junk(int value)
    {
        this.value=value;
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return(value);
    }
}

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        int sum=0;

        for(Junk o:Junk.values())
        {
            sum+=o.getValue();
        }

        System.out.println("sum  = "+sum);
    }
}
```

---

Would display `sum = 1110` on the console, if you give it a try.

Comment: Also note that if no access modifier is specified for the constructor of a *normal class*, the constructor has *default access*. If no access modifier is specified for the constructor of an `enum type`, the constructor is **private**. It is a compile-time error, if the constructor of an `enum type` is declared **public** or **protected**. ***What I mean constructors of an `enum type` are always private even though you don't explicitly declare them.***

Answer (score 1):

```
enum Junk {

    Wrapper(0),
    SilverCoins(150), 
    Dresser(250),
    Sofa(250),
    ChippedBat(0),
    BrokenMicrowave(0),
    SilverWare(35),
    Newspapers(0),
    Book(20),
    Clothes(60),
    Plates(40),
    Cups(25),
    DiningTable(200),
    Chair(30),
    BoxOfPaper(10),
    BucketofPaint(10),
    Watch(30);

    private int value;

    private Junk(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }

}
```

get enum value:

```
int sofaValue = Junk.Sofa.getValue();
```

adding code:

```
int junkSum = 0;

for(Junk junk : junk.values()){
    junkSum += junk.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Brand{
    private static int sum;

    public static int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    public enum Junk  
    {
        Wrapper(0),
        SilverCoins(150), 
        Dresser(250),
        Sofa(250),
        ChippedBat(0),
        BrokenMicrowave(0),
        SilverWare(35),
        Newspapers(0),
        Book(20),
        Clothes(60),
        Plates(40),
        Cups(25),
        DiningTable(200),
        Chair(30),
        BoxOfPaper(10),
        BucketofPaint(10),
        Watch(30);
        private int value;

        private Junk (int value){
            this.value = value;
            sum = sum + value;
        }

        public int getValue(){
            return value;
        }
    }
 }
```

**in main:**

```
System.out.println(Brand.Junk .BoxOfPaper);
System.out.println("sum:"+Brand.getSum());
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
BoxOfPaper
sum:1110
```

Comment: Could you explain what's going on? Interesting how you did it without a for-loop.

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5 its being summed in constructor itself while the enum is created. `sum` is a class level variable.

Answer (score 0):

You first need an accessor method to access the integer value. Say, `.getInt()`. Once you have it, do something like this:

```
int sum = 0;

for (final Junk junk: Junk.values())
    sum += junk.getInt();

// Now sum contains what you want
```

This code does not check for overflows, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
int total=0;

for (Junk j: Junk.values()) {  
 //retrieve each of the values and add it to total
}
```