# Java recollecting the randomly chosen enums and summing it all up

Tags: java, random, enums, sum

A mere continuation of this article

[Java How to get the sum up all the of the values of each enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622010/java-how-to-get-the-sum-up-all-the-of-the-values-of-each-enum)

full source code below

http://pastebin.com/VMGUJmeZ

I have this For loop below, and what I am here to ask you guys for today is how I could recollect all of the randomly chosen enums, and sum up all their values.

```
    for (int i = amount; i > 0; --i){//determines the amount of cycles.
        Junk randomX = Junk.values()[random.nextInt(Junk.values().length)];
//randomly picks an enum 
        System.out.println(randomX);

        }
```

Below me is the solution I did which basically declared a int sum, initialize it and put it in the for loop to collect the values of the enums

```
for (int i = amount; i > 0; --i){

        Junk randomX = Junk.values()[random.nextInt(Junk.values().length)];
        //randomly picks an enum 
        System.out.println(randomX);

        for(Junk o : Junk.values()){

            sum += o.getValue();
            //sorry, I had sum declared and initialized outside of the loop.
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
```

sadly, the output was not desirable

```
Dresser
0
150
400
650
650
650
...
```

I understand that I am basically asking others to help me in writing code for me, but I am unsure of how else to do this.

Also I understand it might be impossible to do considering that the only way to get the sum of the enum's value is by doing it outside of the for loop, which will then make the solution impossible as it will only get all of the values.

Perhaps there is something besides a for loop I could use, that someone could recommend me in using.

Answer (score 2):

You have a second loop

```
for(Junk o : Junk.values()){
  sum += o.getValue();
  //sorry, I had sum declared and initialized outside of the loop.
  System.out.println(sum);
}
```

which is not neccessary. Simply replace this part by

```
sum += randomX.getValue();
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = amount; i > 0; --i){

    Junk randomX = Junk.values()[random.nextInt(Junk.values().length)];
    //randomly picks an enum 
    System.out.println(randomX);

    sum += randomX.getValue();
    System.out.println(sum);
}

System.out.println("grand total: " + sum);
```